# Python BS4 error: No module named html.entities

Tags: python, html

So I installed BS4 with PIP, but when I do

```
from bs4 import beautifulsoup4
```

I get this

```
ImportError: No module named html.entities
```

I've done all the research I can into this as it seems to be a fairly rare problem, and the only thing I could find is to only have one version of python installed, yet I need both python two and three installed so that wouldn't work.

So I was wondering if there's a better way to fix this error, I have read http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#problems-after-installation by the way, there appeared to be nothing in there that would help my situation.

Thanks for your help! And sorry for my formatting

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? `html.entities` is only in Python 3.

Comment: Should `from bs4 import beautifulsoup4` be `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: I was wrong I have it written as BeautifulSoup, and I'm using 3

Comment: Have you tried this package https://pypi.org/project/htmlentities/ .Note I've not tested it because I have python 3.8 on my machine. Worth a shot?